# Layer an image above a div but below text?

Tags: html, css, templates

[Current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/157VV.jpg)

My current progress is shown above ^

Currently, I have a div background of solid black and rounded corners

Above/within that, I want to add the image you see above the text

And then the text and spacer images on top of that

I would share my current code if I knew how to make it plain text so here's a pdf

https://myucdsb-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/belle_fortin_my_ucdsb_ca/EeSBkmriyvtFjYZAvWpOCWcB0gI6FATRPhfzwPAMZPR-nA?e=o4Skxx

Comment: You should add all infomation into this post instead of links to another website, so everyone can more easier to understand your problem without open any another sites.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Edit:
**NOTE**: Keep In mind that HTML reads from the top to the bottom. Meaning, the reason why all the words were below the image was because in your code the image came first and then the writing.
So all I did was move the words from below the image to above the image. Thanks

```html
<div style="border-radius: 25px; background:#000000; padding: 25px; width: 500px; margin:auto;">
      <div class="container">
        <center>
          <div style="color:#5ce600; font-size: 30px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #66ff00; font-family:Apple Chancery;">ANALA</div>
          <div style="color:#5ce600; font-family: Apple Chancery, cursive; font-size: 20px;">From a sparkto a flame</div>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ioaINSW.gif">
        </center>
        <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Times, Times New Roman, serif;color:#ff9933; text-align: center;">Main body text here!</p>
        <center>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ioaINSW.gif" style="display: block;">
          <OOC style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Times, Times New Roman, serif; color:#5ce600;">OOCNotes:</OOC>
        </center>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tHJX2sW/70005cc22fe3a833cb0bd3343612223b-cool-fire-red-aesthetic.jpg" alt="Match" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Close! I'd like the main body text to appear above the image rather than below it though. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, easy fix ! Read the edited answer. Thanks

Comment: That seems to put the image at the very bottom of the table and not behind the text from when I ran it?